# What do I do when I have an interview with company B during my work period with company A and the HR in company B is unresponsive to my email?

Tags: interviewing, ethics, human-resources

I am currently working for company A in the form of a contract, until August. I just started a week ago in company A. Today and I received an interview from company B and ask me to have an interview with them about an upcoming position in September. Company B said they pulled some strings to arrange this interview because I do not meet the requirement but they like me as a person so they want to give me a chance. They scheduled the interview at 12noon.

On the other hand I have to work in company A and my work time is 830am to 430pm. It takes me about 1 and half hour to travel from my home to company A. Likewise from Company A and company B. Company A will not allow me to work from home and Taking half day off is not an option since the commute time will take up more than half day of work, plus the interview time with company B.

I emailed the HR person in company B asking if the interview can be rearranged into another date and time but there was no reply. It is after office hours now.

While I really want to go to the interview in company B I still have to show up to work in company A. I have already taken a day off since I started working last week. I originally planned to take the day off at company A to go to the interview in company B but I am not sure if that is a good thing to take day offs so frequent after started working there not too long ago.

This arrangement was also very sudden that there was not much time for me to talk to the people in company A. I don't want to be seen as someone who is not interested in the work in company A by taking so many day off when I have only been working there for a week. I also don't want to miss the interview opportunity with company B. It is certain that I will not get any response from either company if I am to be in contact with them now.

What should I do?

Comment: Since you're on a short-term contract with company A, hopefully they will be understanding about your need to interview for positions after the end of your contract with them.  I'd either take the day off, or go to work after the interview and stay late, if that is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, why you didn't phone the HR person at company B? This was urgent and understandable to be talked about on phone.

On the other hand, what I would do is open a space in my agenda by getting out of work later. So if going to the interview takes about 3 hours, then you would end your workday at 7:30 pm. It's a late hour but helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do?

If being honest with Company B about your lack of availability doesn't help, then there is little that you can do, other than wait until your contract with Company A expires. At that point, I assume you'll have all day to go on interviews.

You should call them directly (rather than email) first thing in the morning to explain your situation, and to explore other possibilities.

Sometimes these things are just a matter of timing. Somethings things work out, and sometimes they don't.